# How to find in string in the syntax and split them into an array regardless of order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to split an string into separate parts. Here how I want

I got an original string

```
let allString =  'This is the test to replace the string';
```

I will make the original string into array according to an array.

```
let toReplace = [
    {
        string: 'the test'
    },
    {
        string: 'replace'
    },
]
```

The result I want `[ 'This is ', 'the test', ' to ', 'replace', ' the string' ]`.

I got the answer for this already

```
const processedText = toReplace
    .reduce(
      (result, { string }, index) => {
        const parts = result[result.length - 1].split(string);
        const [before, after] = parts;

        const newResult = result.slice();
        const firstPass = index === 0;
        if (firstPass) {
          newResult.shift();
        } else {
          newResult.pop();
        }

        if (before) {
          newResult.push(before);
        }
        if (string) {
          newResult.push(string);
        }
        if (after) {
          newResult.push(after);
        }

        return newResult;
      },
      [allString]
   )
```

The thing is if I change the order of the `toReplace` array, It won't work anymore

```
let toReplace = [
        {
            string: 'replace'
        },
        {
            string: 'the test'
        },
    ]
```

It will skip the 2nd one. Result `[ 'This is the test to ', 'replace', ' the string', 'the test' ]`

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Using capturing groups will keep the separator in the array:

```js
let allString = 'This is the test to replace the string';

const processedText = allString.split(/(the test|replace)/);
console.log(processedText);
```

The order isn't important for this:

```js
let allString = 'This is the test to replace the string';

const processedText = allString.split(/(replace|the test)/);
console.log(processedText);
```

You can dynamically build the regular expression:

```js
let toReplace = [{ string: 'the test' }, { string: 'replace' }];

const re = new RegExp(`(${toReplace.map(el => el.string).join('|')})`);

let allString = 'This is the test to replace the string';

const processedText = allString.split(re);
console.log(processedText);
```

Comment: How about this case
`let toReplace = [{ string: '*' }, { string: 'replace' }];`
I am getting the error of Nothing to repeat when 
`allString = 'This is * the test to replace the string'`

Comment: @Khant You could use `\*` instead of `*`. This is because `*` has a special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: @Khant Or replace `el.string` with `el.string.replace('*', '\*')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the indices of the wanted prases and sort the array by index and get the sliced array with it.

```js
const
    text =  'This is the test to replace the string',
    toReplace = [{ string: 'replace' }, { string: 'the test' }],
    indices = [],
    result = [];

for (const { string } of toReplace) {
    let i = text.indexOf(string);
    while (i !== -1) {
        indices.push([i, string]);
        i = text.indexOf(string, i + string.length);
    }
}

indices.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);

let i = 0, j = 0;

if (indices[j]?.[0] === 0) {
    result.push(indices[j][1]);
    i += indices[j][1].length;
    j++;
}

while (i < text.length && j < indices.length) {
    result.push(text.slice(i, indices[j][0]), indices[j][1]);
    i = indices[j][0] + indices[j][1].length;
    j++;
}

if (text.slice(i)) result.push(text.slice(i));

console.log(result);
console.log(indices);
```